# Proof involving gcd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is the question that I am working on:

> Suppose $a,b \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ with $g = \gcd(a,b)$. Show that $\gcd(\frac{a}{g},\frac{b}{g}) = 1.$

I would like to solve this using Bézout's Identity (I believe that there is a *nicer* way to show this result holds).

**My alternate proof**

We know that $g|a$ and $g|b$. Thus, $\exists k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$gk_1 = a$$ and $$gk_2 = b.$$

We want to show that $gcd(k_1,k_2) = 1.$ Suppose that $d|k_1$ and $d|k_2$ where $d \in \mathbb{N}.$ We want to show that $d = 1.$ Thus, $\exists l,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$a = gdl$$ and $$b = gdm.$$

Thus, $gd|a$ and $gd|b.$ So, $gd$ is a common divisor. So, $gd \leq g,$ or $d \leq 1,$ but $d \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, $d \geq1$. Thus, $d = 1.$ so, the only common divisor of $k_1$ and $k_2$ is $1$. Thus, $gcd(k_1, k_2) = gcd(\frac{a}{g}, \frac{b}{g}) = 1.$

**QED**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: You know there are integers $m$ and $n$ so that $ma+nb = g$. Divide by $g$. What does this tell you?

Comment: So if we divide the linear combination by $g$, we get $m (\frac{a}{g}) + n (\frac{b}{g}) = 1.$  Since $\frac{a}{g}$ and $\frac{b}{g}$ are integers, does this means $g = 1$?

Comment: The *new* gcd is $1$, yes. This either follows from the definition of gcd or by checking that any common divisor must divide $1$.

Comment: Ah yes. I will put the $m$ where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\gcd(\frac a{\gcd(a,b)}, \frac b{\gcd(a,b)})$ divides both $\frac a{\gcd(a,b)}$ and $ \frac b{\gcd(a,b)}$.    So $\gcd(\frac a{\gcd(a,b)}, \frac b{\gcd(a,b)})*\gcd(a,b)$ divides both $\frac a{\gcd(a,b)}*\gcd(a,b) = a$ and $ \frac b{\gcd(a,b)}*\gcd (a,b) = b$.

So $\gcd(\frac a{\gcd(a,b)}, \frac b{\gcd(a,b)})*\gcd(a,b)$ is a common factor $a$ and $b$.

But $\gcd(a,b)$ was the *greatest* common factor so......

....

Bezout's identity:  Let $ak + bj = \gcd(a,b)$ then $\frac a{\gcd(a,b)} *k + \frac b{\gcd(a,b)}*j = 1$.   So .....